# Implementing basic high pass filter using difference equation

Tags: discrete-signals, python, highpass-filter

For the following signal, I am trying to remove the gradual positive drift but retain the spikes using a high pass filter.

[image]

I am aware that I can use implement a high pass filter using difference equation. I am familiar with convolution, and I have implemented simple low pass filter using moving average and first order recursive filter in the past. But I am not sure how to use difference equation to implement a high order filter that fits this particular problem. I am looking for a simple starting point using difference equation that I can tweak around, and then maybe move toward something a bit more complicated.

Any starting point would be appreciated.

---

I've tried difference equation $y[n] = \alpha y[n-1] + x[n] - x[n-1]$
posted on [How to remove or filter the drift problem in measured Strain signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/how-to-remove-or-filter-the-drift-problem-in-measured-strain-signal/27471#27471), but I do not get the expected result. The signal can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/MBXWnqVi) as a Python list, and I chose $\alpha$ value to be 0.8.

[image]

Expected result,
[image]

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you for looking into it. I've tried the difference equation posted on that related question, but I did not get expected result. I've updated the question with additional information.

Comment: OK! I've reopened it. Thanks for adding the extra detail.  It looks like your implementation has an extra difference in there that shouldn't be there. I'll have a quick look now.

Comment: this HPF of yours is a simple DC-blocking filter.  try an $\alpha$ closer to 1.  but keep it strictly less than 1.

Comment: @Quazi_Irfan If you desire a linear-phase DC cancellation filter have a look at the following web page:
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php

Comment: Related: [High Pass filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10118/high-pass-filter)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Can you please forward me to some literature on how to customize the difference equation even further? It is working when I set alpha to 0.99, but I still need to [remove some spikes](https://imgur.com/a/pZC0hP9).

Comment: okay, try setting $\alpha=0.999$ and see what you get.  or try a 2nd-order HPF.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson By second order HPF, do you mean running the same difference equation again on the filtered signal?

Comment: That's one form of second-order where both poles are real.  More generally the two poles of a second-order filter can be both real or both complex conjugates of each other.  Maybe the best quickie reference for you to make a filter would be the [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).  All second-order, one of the filter types is HPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same thing you do. Another possibility is to just do a `detrend` on the data.

[image: My take]

The top plot is your data, and the DC blocker approach.

The bottom plot is your data, and removing the straight line fit through your data.

---

## Python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

alpha = 0.9
b = [1,-1]
a = [1,-alpha]
dc_blocked_data = signal.lfilter(b,a,data)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(dc_blocked_data)

gradient,bias = np.polyfit(np.arange(0,len(data)),data,1)
estimate = gradient*np.arange(0,len(data))+bias
linear_subtraction = np.subtract(data,estimate)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(linear_subtraction)
```

Comment: Good idea. I think it would be even better if you detrend in sections. The slope after a positive and negative peak is quite different, so detrending between the peaks will look better. Of course, you've have to figure how to splice the detrended sections together

Comment: @Hilmar Sure! But that's a whole over level of effort. I'm only in it for the quick points. ;-)

Comment: @PeterK. Thanks. I came up with the exact approach after right after posting this question. But I was wondering if there is any class of difference equation that I can use for this particular problem?